# Ideals with the same Hilbert series

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, soft-question, hilbert-function

Consider a polynomial ring $\mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ that is $\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$-graded by degree. Let $I$ and $J$ be two homogeneous ideals therein with the same Hilbert series, i.e. with their homogeneous components of degree $n$ having the same dimension for any $n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$.

In its most general form my question is whether some kind of relationship between $I$ and $J$ follows from this condition. Or, in slightly different terms, whether one may somehow describe the set of all ideals with a given Hilbert series.

For instance, the aforementioned set of ideals is a poset with respect to taking initial ideals. Are there any general results concerning this poset?

Comment: Look into Hilbert schemes

Comment: Check out lexicographic ideals as well.

Comment: @AviSteiner Thank you! My knowledge of Hilbert schemes is very basic so I will certainly take a closer look. I must, however, say that in the cases I'm interested in $I$ and $J$ are of infinite codimension. Would Hilbert schemes still be of help here?

Comment: @AaronDall Thank you! Could those be the same as the lex-segment ideals from Miller's and Sturmfels's book? I read the corresponding section quite a while ago but, if I'm not mistaken, they show that these ideals are, in a sense, extremal among those with the same Hilbert function and not much apart from that. Should I look elsewhere?

Comment: @imakhlin They’re ideals in a polynomial ring of dimension n. So, their codimemsion (however you’re defining it) is at most n. Certainly not infinite.

Comment: @AviSteiner Lol, sorry, I'm referring to the codimension of the ideal in the ring =D The quotient is infinite-dimensional, in particular, its Hilbert function is a Hilbert _series_ rather than a Hilbert _polynomial_.

Comment: @imakhlin There are two things that are commonly called the codimension of an ideal $I$ in a (commutative unital) ring $R$. In [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Height_of_an_ideal), these are called the height and coheight. When $R$ has finite Krull dimension $n$, both of these quantities are at most $n$. So, I don’t know what you mean by codimension.

Comment: @AviSteiner Here all I meant was the codimension of the vector subspace $I$ inside the vector space $R$, i.e. the dimension of the quotient ring. Anyway, thank you for your advice, I'll look into it.